# There is no cron_email_queue & cron_email_queue_recipients tables in my database. Not sending order confirmation emails, in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, orders, email, cron

My cron jobs are working per 1 minute. But order confirmation emails are not sending.

When I checked in my db, `cron_email_queue` & `cron_email_queue_recipients` **tables are missing**.

What to do? I'm using Magento 2.

> Note: Account creation emails are reaching the user.

Comment: Run command `php bin/magento cron:run` & check `cron_schedule` table.

Comment: i already checked  cron_schedule table. And it runs for every 1 mins.

Answer (score 1):

You can check you email queue in the table **newsletter_queue** than the **core_email_queue** used in M1.

Answer (score 0):

Those tables aren't there in my Magento 2.1.2 installation.

Check to see that the purchaser is getting the mails.

```
Sales -> Orders -> View Order and see if it says "(The order confirmation email was sent)" after the order number.
```

If they are getting the email and its you thats not recieving an order notification then:

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order -> Send Order Email Copy Method -> Separate Email
```

Bcc or "use system value" didn't work for me.